# How to save script (sh) runing with vi command plus how to remove file?

Tags: 20.04, vim

I am installing DUC (Dynamic update client) for NO-IP  DDNS on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

I used help from this site : https://www.blackmoreops.com/2020/11/18/how-to-install-the-noip2-on-ubuntu-and-run-via-systemd-systemctl-noip-dynamic-update-client/

I got stuck when I need to do this:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/src/noip-2.1.9-1# vi /etc/init.d/noip2.sh
```

Paste the following in the file and save it:

```
#######################################################
#! /bin/sh
# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions # uncomment/modify for your killproc
case "$1" in
start)
echo "Starting noip2."
/usr/local/bin/noip2
;;
stop)
echo -n "Shutting down noip2."
killproc -TERM /usr/local/bin/noip2
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
exit 1
esac
exit 0
#######################################################
```

1. I do not know if I need to copy `##########`  at the beginning and end or just everything between those characters.
2. I can't save it or exit (it is not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit or <kbd>F2</kbd> to exit)
3. I think that I have a few files in folder `etc/int.d` that are not needed or they are duplicated:

   ```
   .noip2.sh.swl
   .noip2.sh.swm
   .noip2.sh.swn
   .noip2.sh.swo
   ```

I do not know how to remove them if necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save files edited with vim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252760/how-do-i-save-files-edited-with-vim)

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301119/what-are-swp-files-and-why-are-they-created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't save .bashrc file in VIM ("The swap file ".bashrc.swp" already exists!")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736182/cant-save-bashrc-file-in-vim-the-swap-file-bashrc-swp-already-exists)

Comment: Cannot you use `sudo apt install nano` and the `nano /path/to/file` or you can use `gedit /path/to/file` , VI isn't necessary , it is just a text editor like gedit and nano, And also ### doesn't mean anything

Answer (score 1):

The `#` means whatever follows it will be a comment, so whether you include those lines or not makes no difference.

`vi` doesn't use ctrl+s to save. To write the buffer to disk and quit press escape followed by `:wq` (short for write and quit).
[Here](https://github.com/hakluke/how-to-exit-vim) are some other ways to exit vi(m).

As for the files, they are temporary files created by `vi` and will go away when you close the editor.